# My file name contains emoji, how do I commit it to git?

Tags: git, github

I have an added file waiting to be committed to git.

The file is named `1__Weather.py` in my `scripts/` directory. After passing git command: `git add .` the file name is decoded to `1_\360\237\217\240_Weather.py`.

Now I have:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   "scripts/1_\360\237\217\240_Weather.py.py"
```

How do I commit this file?

I tried `git commit "scripts/1_\360\237\217\240_Weather.py.py"` but the git throws the error below:

`error: pathspec 'scripts/1_360237217240_Home.py' did not match any file(s) known to git`

I know the error is generated to the file name.

I thought with `git commit -m "commit message"` without call the file name might commit the file but I have other files and and and want to commit them separately.

Any ide how to get this done?

Comment: Do not use special characters or emojies in file name

Comment: BTW: You have to use `git add <filename>` before you can commit it

Comment: Yeah but `git add .` adds all files as well, I already have the file added but can't commit it.

Comment: `\\` is a special character in file names. That will be the problem. And that is the reason why you should not use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is that *Git* does not care one way or another about these kinds of special characters in a path or pathspec.  Your *OS* may or may not care: apparently it doesn't care so much as to prohibit it, so you're fine there.

What's going on with your `git status` output is this:

> ```
> Changes to be committed:
>   (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
>         new file:   "scripts/1_\360\237\217\240_Weather.py.py"
> ```

When Git goes to print a character, if the character's encoding is an ordinary printable character between 32 and 126 decimal (ASCII space through `~`), it prints it by emitting that code, but if not, it checks `core.quotePath`.  If this is `true` or unset, it prints an octal representation of the character preceded by a backslash (note: this isn't a complete description, but rather just enough to cover the above case).

The *encoding* of the special character—you say this character is , which is the Earth Globe emoji whose Unicode encoding is U+1F30E—has, on your system, become `0o360` (240 decimal) + `0o237` (159 decimal) + `0o217` (143 decimal) + `0o240` (160 decimal).  (I've used Python-style numerics here, and a bit of Python below.)  So that's what you see here: `\360\237\217\240`, representing those four bytes.

This seems a bit weird because the UTF-8 encoding for U+1F30E is different from those four bytes:

```
>>> w = ""
>>> w.encode("utf8")
b'\xf0\x9f\x8c\x8e'
>>> for i in w.encode("utf8"): print(oct(i))
... 
0o360
0o237
0o214
0o216
```

The UTF-8 decoding of the text you've shown here is the  (House) emoji, U+1F3E0.

When *typing in* this file name, you don't have to do anything special at all.  That is, don't type in the funny backslash-y sequence.  Just type in the file's *name*.  Git is merely *encoding the file name on output* based on a concern that it will mess with your window or otherwise display inappropriately.  If you don't mind the potential for messing with your window, you can just turn `core.quotePath` off:

```
git -c core.quotePath=false status
```

for instance, or `git config core.quotePath false`.  See [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for details.

**It's generally not a great idea to put such characters into file names.**  *Git* handles it just fine, but some OSes don't.  If you avoid these file names, you won't run into OS-related problems.

Answer (score 0):

Because your file name contains special characters, But there are ways to work around it.

**Option 1:** Is to commit first your files which filenames do not contain special characters first and after that, commit the **scripts** folder.

**Option 2:**

Create a folder in `scripts` directory, move the file to that new folder you created and commit the folder.

For example:

```
scripts
  filesWithSpecialsNames
     1__Weather.py
```

Now you can `git add scripts/filesWithSpecialsNames`

Your git output massage will now look like:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   "scripts/filesWithSpecialsNames/1_\360\237\217\240_Weather.py.py"
```

Remember you now have a directory called **filesWithSpecialsNames** that holds your file with special characters

Now you are going to `git commit scripts/filesWithSpecialsNames` which will commit the folder. Your file is now been committed.